# How to manage multiple conditions under route method

Tags: python, flask

I am working on something like Advance filter search in Flask, where i have inputs as:

### index.html: (form)

```html
    <form action="/search" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="letter" name="numbersearch" placeholder="Enter car number">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="Select1" name="brandsearch">
            <option value="">select brand</option>
            <option value="A">AUDI</option>
            <option value="B">BMW</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="Select2" name="typesearch">
            <option value="">select type</option>
            <option value="Au">Automatic</option>
            <option value="Mn">Manual</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="word" name="carsearch" placeholder="Enter automotive name">
      </div>
    </form>
```

### In views.py :

I have been writing under one route as:

```
mod_automobile = Blueprint('dictionary', __name__)

@mod_automobile .route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@mod_automobile .route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    numbersearch=request.args.get('numbersearch') or None
    brandsearch=request.args.get('brandsearch') or None
    typesearch=request.args.get('typesearch') or None
    carsearch=request.args.get('carsearch') or None

    ''' Here I am writing conditions for single/multiple combination selection's and search database'''

    if numbersearch and brandsearch: '''If user selects only these two'''
        '''.............'''
        return render_template('sometemplate1.html')'''new template'''

    elif numbersearch:  '''If user selects only numbersearch'''
        '''...............'''
        return render_template('sometemplate2.html')'''a new template'''
    elif brandsearch:
        '''....'''

    ....'''similarly all possible conditions''''
```

Here I have limited conditions so I can somehow do this, but I am afraid if such conditions are many how to manage them ?,

also Is it good to write all conditions under single route method?

I am using Mongo DB , and each selected condition have it's own collection or multiple collections to search so that i am unable to write a dynamic query there ()

### for sample:

I am searching for automotive name say 'porsche' , I am maintaing collection names as `a_collection` (for all cars starting with `a` information),similarly `b`,`c`,...`z`

for this it goes to condition as per above*,

```
elif carsearch:
        collection_name=word[0].lower()+'_collection'
        cars=db[collection_name]
        data=cars.find({'car':carsearch})
        return render_template('carsearch.html',data=data)
```

sample document format which is same in all collections(p_collection):

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e0c70f22b15fc7b3b218a94"
    },
    "car": "Porsche",
    "carset_id": "76c6ebfae9",
    "details": [{
        "id": "4c21c72afa",
        "engine_model": "flat-six"
    }]
}
```

Looking for a suggestion on how to manage this in a more meaningful format , any help is appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to manage many possible conditions.
Put the search selection arguments into one tuple, such as:

```
(True, False, True, True)
```

Then, you have a dictionary populated with selection tuples as keys and functions to execute as values.

Example:

```
user_selection_handler = {
(True, False, True, True): func
}
```

Obtain the necessary function from this dictionary:

```
numbersearch=request.args.get('numbersearch') or None
brandsearch=request.args.get('brandsearch') or None
typesearch=request.args.get('typesearch') or None
carsearch=request.args.get('carsearch') or None

to_execute = user_selection_handler.get((numbersearch, brandsearch, typesearch, carsearch))
```

Now call the function that was selected:

```
to_execute()
```

Done!

Note: this way, you can define functions somewhere else in your code and also save yourself from numerous if/elif conditions.

Comment: That was a great idea , so all the possible combinatons in a tuple like i have (True, False, True, True) (False,True,True, True)(True,True ,False,True) and so on.......name each with some name ? how could i call them ? any possible example extending to this would be more helpful mate

Comment: @Codenewbie you could call a function as such: example_dictionary[example_tuple]()  naming the tuples is optional, as the dictionary is indexed via matching the contents of the tuple generated by your user’s selections with one of the possible combinations in your dictionary’s keys (you will have to populate these keys into the dictionary somewhere in your code ).